# MongoDB get all values of 1 field

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, subquery, database

So I know that  in mongodb, I can get all values and then iterate through them but I was wondering if in mongodb there is an option to get only a certain field.

So for example suppose my collection is structured as follows:

```
{_id:
    {
    field1,field2,field3}
    }
{description:
    {
    field1,field2,field3,
    data:{
    field1,field2,field3
    }
    }
    }
{otherdata:
{field1,field2,field3}
}
```

Now, I need the value of description.data.field1 so any suggestions on how to do that?

So far I have tried using following commands:

```
db.module.collection.description.data.find()
db.module.collection.description.find({'data':1})
db.module.collection.find('description.data.data':1})
```

But obviously, they did not work.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, the structure of your JSON isn't correct. The correct structure should be:

```
{
_id:{
    field1: "",
    field2: "",
    field3: ""
},
description:{
    field1: "",
    field2: "",
    field3: "",
    data:{
        field1: "",
        field2: "",
        field3: ""
    }
},
otherdata:{
    field1: "",
    field2: "",
    field3: ""
}
}
```

Now for what you need, you can use `Projections`

Something like this:

```
db.collection.find({}, {description.data.field1: 1})
```

Comment: I tried that but then I get the data as follows: description,_id for some reason. I thought that  the data might be actually references so I tried printing it as a json array but to the same conclusion. any idea why that may be the case?

Comment: Sorry, I just checked, I for some reason was doing find_one and did not even notice, it  gave me the first array which was simply for  test and hence my output was messed up. Thanks a tonne!