# How do I get values of same key from all documents in MongoDB using Java?

Tags: java, mongodb

I am new in working on mongodb. Here is my Mongodb documents I only want the name values.

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5da527f784a58d78fcd0b177"),
    "name" : "Jabed",
    "email" : "jabed@gmail.com",
    "Sex" : "male",
    "age" : "19",
    "address" : "Kochukhet, Dhaka",
    "Contct" : "01797259329"
}

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5da6f415f2bdee4b90cf41d0"),
    "name" : "Bulbul Gulzer Deb",
    "email" : "gulzer.deb@gmail.com",
    "Sex" : "male",
    "age" : "19",
    "address" : "Narinda, Dhaka",
    "Contct" : "01756223666"
}

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5dd771907607c3e12d9183d7"),
    "name" : "Aniruddha Dey",
    "email" : "aniruddha.dey@gmail.com",
    "Sex" : "male",
    "age" : "14",
    "address" : "Narinda, Dhaka",
    "Contct" : "01745706020"
}
```

Expected output will be

```
Jabed
Bulbul Gulzer Deb
Aniruddha Dey
```

Comment: db.collection.distinct("NameOfTheField") or yo can see link this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36460377/mongodb-get-all-values-of-1-field

Answer (score 0):

Use the projection:

```
db.yourdocument.find( {}, { name: 1, _id: 0 } )
```

More control over projected fields can be found [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/project-fields-from-query-results/#return-the-specified-fields-and-the-id-field-only)

Comment: How can i do it using java?